# Проблема с сохранением PIL в PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pil, pillow

Я пытался сохранить массив PIL images в 1 PDF файл. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images) я нашел на него ответ (от пользователя ilovecomputer. Я пытался написать что то по аналогии с ним:

```
    stamped_pages_images = stamp_pages(pdf_pages_images, pdf_pages_texts)
    #List of images: Pdf's pages with QR and warning text
    print(stamped_pages_images)
    stamped_pages_images[0].save(get_file_name(FILE_PATH) + "_stamped_" + get_time() + ".pdf",
                                 resolution = 100.0,
                                 save_all=True,
                                 append_images=stamped_pages_images[1:])
```

Это программа выводит:

```
[<PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E35E5B0248>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B4B648>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B56588>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B565C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B60E48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B62A48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67588>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67648>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67708>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67788>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67848>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67908>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B679C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67A88>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67B48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67C08>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67CC8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67D88>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67E48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67F08>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B67FC8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B710C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71188>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71248>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71308>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B713C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71488>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71548>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71608>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B716C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71788>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71848>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71908>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B719C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71A88>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71B48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71C08>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71CC8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71D88>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71E48>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71F08>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B71FC8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B760C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76188>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76248>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76308>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B763C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76488>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76548>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76608>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B766C8>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76788>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2339x1654 at 0x2E300B76848>]
```

Так что дело не в функции `stamp_pages`, так как объекты PIL.Image создаются.
Но сам PDF не сохраняется, вернее сохраняется странным образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам файл весит 0 байт и не имеет разширения. При попытке сменить его на .pdf и открыть хром выдаёт ошибку что пдф поврежден. Старнно что у файла нет расширения, и что вместо 22:58 написано 22 (Функция get_time возвращает строку - показания часов сейчас)

```
import datetime

def get_time():
    # Returns smth. like this: "12:00" or "02:51"
    return str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[0:5]
```

Comment: Попытка вынести 0-ой эл-т отдельно не увенчалось успехом (img = stamped_pages_images[0]
    img.save(...................)

Comment: Так же аналогичный код вот [здесь](https://datatofish.com/images-to-pdf-python/)

Comment: вы хотите сохранить изображение в `.pdf` файл ?

Comment: Типа многостраничного скана. Кстати программа convert умеет

Comment: Да я хочу сохранить массив из N изображений в N-cтраничный pdf файл, так что бы каждая страница соответсвовала 1-ому изображению.

Comment: Довольно странно, если заменить get time на "00:00" то всё работает) (Вот так:     img.save(get_file_name(FILE_PATH) + "_stamped_" +  ".pdf",
                                 resolution = 100.0,
                                 save_all=True,
                                 append_images=stamped_pages_images[1:]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что название файла не могло содержать знак ':', так что я просто переделал функцию get_time таким образом:

```
import datetime

def get_time():
    # Returns smth. like this: "12:00" or "02:51"
    return str(str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[0:5]).replace(":", "-")
```

P.S. Довольно странно, что PIL не выдаёт ошибку при попытке сохранить. Я написал на гитхаб разработчикам что бы они это исправили это (или рассказали почему этого не проcходит)) Как только я получу ответ, то напишу его в коментариях.

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4861